# Google Cloud and Wordpress Themes/Plugins

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, themes

I have just finished uploading the content of my wordpress site to google cloud.  But I am now facing a huge limitation due to no I/O ability. I am posting this to see if anybody has devised a work-around.

I need to install Headway Themes and upload a package of buttons (Max Buttons Pro), I also have troubles with installing the s2member Pro edition.

Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

Themes & Plugins have to be downloaded and extracted into you wordpress project folder and re-uploaded to appengine.

Typical workflow:

1. Download desired theme (Usually as a .zip file)
2. Extract the .zip file into wordpress/wp-content/themes (you will see default themes here...theres also a folder for plugins)
3. Upload your project to appengine (Don't worry this will not overwrite your data)

You will then see the themes or plugins show up on your wordpress dashboard.

Comment: Was this comment mistakenly placed?